# Typescript: Why using `as` in curly braces import?

Tags: javascript, typescript

As title: for curly braces import let me use the following as an example to express what I mean:

```
import { find as findCustomer } from './resources/customer'
```

I know about the `import * as foo from './resources/customer'` is just to use `foo` as an object to pack all the exports in `'./resources/customer'`. But here I think the meaning of as in `{ find as findCustomer }` is different. So what does it mean? Why&When wee need them? Thanks

Comment: This is [explained in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module has an export named `find`.

If you were to `import { find } from './resources/customer'` then it would be assigned to a local variable named `find`.

By saying `as findCustomer` you assign it to a local variable named `findCustomer` instead.

This:

- Gives you a more informative name for it
- Can help you avoid conflicting with another variable named `find` (e.g. which might be imported from another module)

Comment: Thank you. I think my confusion comes from that it is also used to cast type (in TypeScript for sure).